# I'm confused as to where I would instantiate objects in angular

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, inheritance, angularjs

I just looked through angularjs, and it looks great! But I'm confused about some of the little things. For one, where do I define objects that I want to instatiate elsehwere, and how do I get them there? That seems vague, so here's an example

I have a LogObject class that many of the objects in my simple app derive from. I extend them for Tasks, Notes, Events, etc. Then I have TaskController, and a TaskModel that handles storage and instantiating of Tasks. Now, I understand the angular way to do this is with a TaskController that utilizes a TaskService for storage and other operations. But where/what do I declare the Task object as? A value? And can I just make LogObject a value, and extend from it?

```
PA.value('LogObject',function(){
  this.title;
  this.created = new Date();
  this.text;
  this.id;
});

PA.value('Task',function(LogObject){
  angular.extend(this,LogObject)
  this.due;
  this.etc;
  this.timeLeft = function(){
 //calculate time left 
}
});
```

EDIT

Factories worked great for most of what I want, but I can't seem to get extending factories right
http://jsfiddle.net/22QLt/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some issues with your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22QLt/2/), so I tweaked it a little bit to get it working: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22QLt/5/)

The first problem was that your controller wasn't wired up to your module.

I added a body tag:

```
<body ng-app='myapp'> ... </body>
```

And change the controller declaration to

```
app.controller("HelloCtrl", function($scope, Log, DueLog){ /*...*/ });
```

The second problem was your use of `angular.extend`. It's not a Backbone-style extend, that gives you sugar for prototypal inheritance. It just copies from object to another. So I edited your factories to manually implement prototypal inheritance.

Here's all the JS:

```
//angular.js example for factory inheritance
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('Log', function(){
    function Log(t) {
        this.title = t;
    }
    Log.prototype = {
        setTitle: function(t){
            this.title = t; 
            return this; // Returning the instance for chaining.
        }
    };
    return Log;
});

app.factory('DueLog', ['Log',function(Log){
    function DueLog(d) {
        Log.call(this);
        this.due = d;
    }
    DueLog.prototype = new Log();

    return DueLog;
}]);

app.controller('HelloCtrl', function($scope, Log, DueLog) {
    $scope.x = new Log("a").setTitle('x');
    $scope.y = new DueLog("tomorrow").setTitle('y');
});
```

Hopefully this helps you understand how some of these pieces fit together.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use an Angular Factory :

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('serviceId', ['$http', function($http) {
  var items = [];
  return function(name) {
    var o = {name: name};
    items.push(o);
    return o;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I usually do it, unless there's a code example just at the beginning of the said link. Edited to add a code sample

Comment: Wait, so when a factory is included in the parameters (for DI), does the object it's included in get an instance? Sorry, can you give me an example of this with my objects above?

Comment: I tried injection + extension. which is my main issue, finding an angular object that i can later subclass and instantiate. The instantiation part works, but I cant seem to extend. Why doesn't this work? http://jsfiddle.net/22QLt/2/